# Select all column excluding auto incremented column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select All column name from table excluding auto incremented column in sql server 
I tried something but i get only auto incremented column 
My code is

```
  Select COLUMN_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
and COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') = 1
order by TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Do this.

```
Select COLUMN_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
and COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') <>  1
order by TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: Select COLUMN_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = 'tbl_employee'
and COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') <>  1
order by TABLE_NAME  if i change my table name like some other table its showing NULL